# Prevent log4j2 from creating parent folder of a log file if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, log4j2

As the title of the question states, is it possible to avoid creating parent folders of log4j2 File appender log file if they don't exist?
Actually, when I pass the non-existing parent folder of the file appender log it will be created automatically by log4j2.
I have already tried to see if there is an attribute on the `File` tag but there is nothing.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

```
<Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="${sys:app.home}/app.log"
            ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: That seems like an odd goal - what would you have it do instead, fail?  It shouldn't be hard to check for this situation *before* invoking it.

Comment: I would like it to fail if it doesn't find the parent folder, or simply do nothing.

Comment: Are you specifying a logging.path flag somewhere in your program?

Comment: @kirishna do you mean `fileName="${sys:app.home}/app.log"` from above.

Comment: No, apart from that. I use logback in spring boot and if I want it to fail, I specify the logging.path flag (which is in the properties file) with a folder that should exist. Do you use a framework?

Comment: No, I'm not using a framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option. Here is source code of FileAppender where you can see creating of parent folder. If you want to avoid creating folder then you can create your own inheritor of FileAppender and override setFile method.

```
public synchronized void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize)
                                                        throws IOException {
....
FileOutputStream ostream = null;
try {
      ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
   String parentName = new File(fileName).getParent();
      if (parentName != null) {
         File parentDir = new File(parentName); 
         if(!parentDir.exists() && parentDir.mkdirs()) { //This is were parent folders are created
            ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
         } else {
            throw ex;
         }
      } else {
         throw ex;
      }
}
....
```